# if $D$ denotes a circle with positive radius passing through the origin, then f maps $D$ \ {$0$} to__________

Tags: complex-analysis

Given  that  C is  complex field . consider the mobius transformation  $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} $, $z\in C$ , $z \neq 0$. if $D$ denotes a circle with positive radius passing through the origin, then f maps $D$ \ {$0$} to

1) a circle

2) a line

3) a  line passing through the origin.

4) a  line  not passing through the origin.

my answer : i take  $z = e^{iθ}$ now $ f(z) = e^{-iθ}$

now  by theorem by Mobius  Transformation   theorem,,,it map Circle to circle...as  D \   {0}  is connected   as  continious  image of connected set is connecteds...

so option 1) and option  3)  is the  only correct answer

Comment: $z = e^{i \theta}$  is not a “circle passing through the origin”

Comment: I thought that a circle passing through the origin meant that the origin is on the circle, not the center of the circle. If that's the case, say that the center of the circle is on the real axis, then $z=Re^i\theta+R$

Comment: if 3) were correct, then there would be some $z \in D$ such that $|f(z)|<\epsilon$  i.e. would map to a point very close to the origin.  But that would mean that $|z|$ is very far from the origin.  So, we can eliminate that one.